# Unable to create SqlMap for PersistenceClient with Cairngorm Persistence Library

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, air, persistence, cairngorm

i am trying to create a persistence client object in the following way:

```
var create:Create = new Create();
create.sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REPOFILE( REPOFILEID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, CHECKSUM TEXT, BYTES INTEGER, CREATED INTEGER, UPDATED INTEGER, ISDIRECTORY INTEGER )";

var sqlMap:SqlMap = new SqlMap( { createRepoFileTable : create } );

connectionManager = new ConnectionManagerFactory().createConnectionManager();
persistenceClient = new PersistenceClient( sqlMap, connectionManager );
```

the problem i am encountering is that the "map" property of the sqlmap stays not retrievable even though there is a valid "_maps" array inside the sqlmap object.

```
maps    [] (@b812d09)   
    [0] Object (@b103d61)   
        createRepoFileTable com.adobe.cairngorm.persistence.api.grammar.Create (@b103a91)       
    length  1
```

when trying to execute the create table sql, the statement factory complains:

```
Error: SQLERROR0014: Statement 'createRepoFileTable' not found in SQL map
```

somehow the sqlmap class is unable to copy the properties of the object passed to it to the map property using the ObjectUtil class.

i do not want to use an mxml file and i also do not want to use spicelib like in the example.

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured out that in my case somehow the calls in the SqlMap class to the spicelib components didn't work:

```
var classInfo:ClassInfo=ClassInfo.forInstance(source);
var properties:Array=classInfo.getProperties();
```

the properties array was always empty.

however, i took the persistence lib's source code and changed the loop in the ObjectUtil's to go over the object's properties directly:

```
for (var propertyName:String in source)
```

now it works, although i am not really happy having modified the ObjectUtil class... maybe someone has a better take on this.